# PHP: comparisons and swaps counting

Tags: php

i have an assignment in PHP : i need to create 100 "Collatz" lists (from 1 to 100),  after that i need to sort each list with bubble-sort sorting and then count the number of comparisons and swaps for every list that i sorter.
In The end, i need to print comparisons and swaps counts for every list.
My problem is counting the comparisons and swaps for each sort.

this is my main file:
For each counter i created an array and created indexes for them.

```
<?php
include 'func.php';

$collatz = array();
$bubble_equal_count=array(0);
$bubble_swap_count=array(0);

for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    
    $collatz[$i] = createCollatz($i);
    echo "<pre>The original array is:<br>";
    print_r($collatz[$i]);
    echo "<br>The bubble sort array is:</br>";
    bubbleSort($collatz,$bubble_equal_count,$bubble_swap_count,$equal_index,$swap_index);
    selectionSort($collatz,$selection_equal_count,$selection_swap_count,$equal_index,$swap_index);
    echo "<br>";
    $equal_index+=1;
    $swap_index+=1;
    echo "equals=" . $bubble_equal_count[$equal_index];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "swaps=" . $bubble_swap_count[$swap_index];
}
?>
```

And this is the functions file with the "collatz" creating and the bubble sort:
In the bubble sort function im getting the counters arrays and their indexes and trying to store the count in each index.

```
function createCollatz($n)
{
    $collatz = array();
    $i=0;
    $collatz[$i]=$n;
    while($n>1)
    {
        
        if($n&1)
            $n=3*$n+1;
        else
            $n=$n/2;
        $i++;
        $collatz[$i]=$n;
    }
    return $collatz;
}

function bubbleSort($arr,&$bubble_equal_count,&$bubble_swap_count,$equal_index,$swap_index) 
{ 
    $n = sizeof($arr); 
   
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)  
    { 
        for ($j = 0; $j < $n - $i - 1; $j++)  
        { 
            $bubble_equal_count[$equal_index]++;
            if ($arr[$j] > $arr[$j+1]) 
            { 
                $bubble_swap_count[$swap_index]++;
                $t = $arr[$j]; 
                $arr[$j] = $arr[$j+1]; 
                $arr[$j+1] = $t; 
                
            } 
        } 
    }
    
    
}
```

This is an example for the errors im getting:

```
The original array is:
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 16
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 1
)


Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\collatz2\func.php on line 28



Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\collatz2\func.php on line 48




Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\collatz2\first.php on line 27

equals=


Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\collatz2\first.php on line 29

swaps=
```

Soo , this is not working and i cant find a solution, help me guys!

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop needs to terminate 1 step earlier.

Bubble sort goes through the list comparing adjacent pairs i.e. indexes **[(0,1), (1,2), ... ]**, and on the first iteration, this has to reach the last pair **(maxIndex - 1, maxIndex)**.

Your implementation expresses these pairs as the values at index `$j` and `$j + 1`, but currently `$j + 1` will go out of bounds.

**The TLDR:**
Set `$n = sizeof($arr) - 1`,
and change the inner loop to terminate when `$j < $n - $i`